# Can't access messages on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

As of a week ago, I am unable to access any new messages that people send me on http://careers.stackoverflow.com

[image]

The image above is all that I get when I press on a message, as if the ajax request failed.  Could someone please look into the issue for me?

Thanks!

Comment: It maybe because you were robbed,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug on our end, though it looks like it only started in the logs about 4 hours ago.    We're working on a new messaging feature and a bad assumption snuck its way in there.  I have a fix going out shortly.

Comment: Loved the "bad assumption snuck its way in there" - making the bug sound human! ;)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Nick!

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this as well, and decided to take a look with Firefox's Web Console. When I reloaded the page sent to me in my email notification, this is what happened:

1. `GET http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/287540/messages/223743`, got a `200 OK` back
2. [bunch of random CSS, images, javascript]
3. `POST http://careers.stackoverflow.com/xsrf-refresh` with an XMLHttpRequest, got a `200 OK` back; this seems to be happening every few minutes, pretty straightforward.
4. `POST http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/287540/messages/223743` with an XMLHttpRequest, for some reason? Maybe my web chops aren't doing so hot, but that looks kind of inane, especially with `Content-Length:0`? Anyway, got a `302 FOUND` back, with the target URL `/error?aspxerrorpath=%2Fusers%2F287540%2Fmessages%2F223743` .
5. `GET http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=%2Fusers%2F287540%2Fmessages%2F223743`, naturally, with an XMLHttpRequest. This one came back with a `500 InternalServerError` and a standardized-looking error page in the body ("We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site", etc.). I kinda would have expected to get just the `500` rather than `302` and then `500` but I'll hazard a guess that that's standard practice. The response body only showed up in the logs, in any case. I got the same exclamation point as you rendered at this point (there's a `GET` for the exclamation point too after the `500` response).

Like I said, my web development-fu's not quite up to snuff but that `POST` looks pretty fishy, at least to someone used to Rails and REST.

**EDIT:** Same problem in Safari, just for completeness.